# Identify words that appear in less than 1% of the corpus documents

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, counter, tf-idf

I have a corpus of customer reviews and want to identify rare words, which for me are words that appear in less than 1% of the corpus documents.

I already have a working solution, but it is far too slow for my script:

```
# Review data is a nested list of reviews, each represented as a bag of words
doc_clean = [['This', 'is', 'review', '1'], ['This', 'is', 'review', '2'], ..] 

# Save all words of the corpus in a set
all_words = set([w for doc in doc_clean for w in doc])

# Initialize a list for the collection of rare words
rare_words = []

# Loop through all_words to identify rare words
for word in all_words:

    # Count in how many reviews the word appears
    counts = sum([word in set(review) for review in doc_clean])

    # Add word to rare_words if it appears in less than 1% of the reviews
    if counts / len(doc_clean) <= 0.01:
        rare_words.append(word)
```

Does anyone know a faster implementation for this? It seems to be very time-consuming to iterate for each individual words through each individual review.

Thanks in advance and best wishes,
Marcus

Comment: `set([w for doc in doc_clean for w in doc])` => `{w for doc in doc_clean for w in doc}` saves the list creation, creates the set directly. But the answer below is even better

Comment: same thing: don't pass a list to sum, just pass the gencomp.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre can you explain "pass the gencomp" more in detail?

Comment: yes, don't do `sum([x for x in ...])` just do `sum(x for x in ...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but it is easy to understand and maintain, and I frequently use it myself. I use the Counter and Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
```

Apply the counter to each document and construct a term-frequency matrix:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(Counter, doc_clean)))
```

Some fields in the matrix are undefined. They correspond to the words that do not occur in particular document. Count the occurrences:

```
counts = df.notnull().sum()
```

Now, select the words that do not occur often enough:

```
rare_words = counts[counts < 0.05 * len(doc_clean)].index.tolist()
```

Comment: But this approach only determines the relative frequency of words with respect to the total corpus, right? I specifically want to search words that appear in less than 1% of the documents. If the word "AAA" is not included in the first 999 documents, but the last document is "AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA .." then it still should be a rare word.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I changed the answer.

Comment: Note: TF and DF might be different though. The OP code seems to be asking for DF `#Count in how many reviews the word appears` ;P I encourage the OP user to look at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lxRclJablHF-veuRzWBgJ9gaqMNo6fPa/view

Comment: @alvas The answer calculates DF.

Comment: Yep, I think it's good to that readers knows the difference =)

Comment: BTW, here's a cool trick: `df = list(map(Counter, documents))`, then `tf = sum(df, Counter())` and `all_counts = sum(tf.values())` =)